# Is it a limited access to Typo3 backend? How to create a box structure into a page in this situation?

Tags: content-management-system, typo3, typo3-6.1.x, typo3-4.5

a customer give me the access to its Typo3 website backend to make some changes on some pages. From what I have understand it is a subsite of a biggers site

I am very new in Typo3 world but I am thinking that I have not a full access to the backend.

This is what I see when I enter in the backend using my credentials:

[image]

As you can see seems that the backend is not complete, infact I only have the following voices:

1. **Page**: where I can modify the pages structure
2. **View**: where I have the prewview in the backend of the pages
3. **List**: what exactly do it?

Then, as you can say, I also have a **File** section that contains some folders (I think that this contains the files used in the website and the files that can be dowload from the site

Finally there is the **User Settings** section: I think that it contains the settings related to my user

So I have some question for you:

1. Is this a limited permission administration panel?

If the answer is YES I ask youhow can I solve the following problem: **I have to create some colored boxes into a specific page. Each of these boxes simply must contain text or links.**

From what I have understand (asking here and reading the official documentation) to do this operation might be convenient to use TypoScript (TypoScript reads content which is stored in the database, prepares it for display and then renders it on the frontend)

Ok but...in this case I have no access to the template and I have no access to TypoScript.

So what could I do to create these colored boxes?

The only idea that I have is the following one:

1. In the backend I go in the Page section and I open the settings related to the page that I have to modify
2. I **create a new record** in the **Normal colum** (that represent the content area of my website)
3. Here I inser a new **Plain HTML** element and in this element I insert my HTML (with inline CSS) structure that manually build my boxex and its content

Or have I any other chance? The problem is that seems that my access is very very limited in what can I use of Typo3.

Tnx
Andrea

Answer (score 0):

yes, your backend access is limited.

To build colored boxes, you usually would do this (if this works is dependent on the actual setup):

1. Create a content element (as you described), but choose "Regular Text" as type.
2. Enter your text in the richt text editor, and create the links you want.
3. There *should* be a style in one of the three dropdowns at the top of the editor that makes the current paragraph or list appear as a colored box. It would only provide some colors that match the website theme. This is the part that needs configuration from the administrator of the site, so if its not there, you should ask your admin to provide it.
4. If there is no such styling option configured, you can use the <> symbol in the editor to edit the underlying HTML and add the styles inline. That HTML is not final, it will be postprocessed, so don't change too much - your changes might get lost.